# Как указать прямого потомка в SCSS?

Tags: scss, sass

В css это можно сделать так:

```
div { 
color: grey; 
} 
div>span { 
color: blue; 
}
```

Как это сделать в SCSS?
Типа:

```
div { 
color: grey; 

>span { color: blue; } 
}
```

Comment: вы правильно написали код, ">" означает, что все теги "span", которые идут после "div" будут синими, те "span", которые имеют ещё более глубокую вложенность уже будут серые.

Answer (score 0):

Да.

```
div { 
  color: grey; 

  > span {
    color: blue;
  } 
  
  & > p {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

[image: скриншот]